# How to demand schedule Job?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have `UI` defined `build pipeline` with two agent jobs:

[image: two agent jobs]

I want to [demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) that the second one will run only on [schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) runs.

How can I add this demand?

Comment: You can't specify demands (or variables) in the schedule runs, it just takes the default. why do you need it?

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk, I don't want to add demand to the schedule runs, I want to add demand to the job to run only on schedule trigger and not with PR/commit/manual trigger.

Comment: Ok, you can use a condition, see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [a custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) to the job:

[image]

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
```